# CEdit not set focus automatically

Tags: windows, mfc

I'v create an Edit control dynamic by calling the constructor function and the Create function of `CEdit`:

```
m_pMyEdit = new CEdit;
m_pMyEdit->Create(style,zindex,100,100,100,100,pParentWindow,ID);
```

As you know, we can pass the `this` to the parent window parameter or set this parameter to another window. In my code, I passed the parent window parameter the value of:

```
CWnd::FromHandle(GetDesktopWindow())
```

This piece of code can get a pointer of `CWnd (CWnd*)` from the specific handle. Now run program and the Edit window shows at the position as we expect, and the caret shows in the Edit control and the focus is activited. But when I moved this edit to somewhere else, for example, move it to:

```
RECT rect = {200,200,100,100};
```

the caret disappear and the focus has been killed, further more, when I move the cursor on it, click mouse, the caret not appear and the focus not set any more. I have read the MSDN again and again, but I don't know why this happens.

By the way, the `m_pMyEdit` is the var of `CEdit`, I haven't derived the `CEdit` class yet.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: @IInspectable,Thanks for reply!but i don't think so.because this situation happens too when i set the parent window param its value to 'this' and move it to somewhere else.In my apinion ,no matter where the Edit control is(although the msdn says this param usually a CDialog),think about the mechanim of message translation from the system to application.

Comment: If you move a window the window gets focus. After the move is finished you could reset focus to Edit control. Unless I misunderstood. Your issue is not clear to me.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle,YES,you're right.I should overide some virtual functions or message handlers